# Error while using math packages with pdf/a-1

Tags: amsmath, pdfx

I get the error `Undefined control sequence. $\dot{\bar{x}}$` if I combine any of the listed math packages together with the pdfx-package. Both $\dot{x}$ and $\bar{x}$ just work fine.
I need the PDF to be in PDF/A-1b format but would also like to use the math packages. Does anyone has a hint what to do in this case?

```
\documentclass[english, dvipsnames]{scrbook}                

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{aligned-overset}
%\usepackage{underoverlap}              
%\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
    $\dot{\bar{x}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, I get an error just by using this MWE as it is. But a different one. You might want to provide the full log file.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512646/2388. Be aware that as @daleif mentioned  pdfx is completly broken in a current texsystem (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/610359/2388), so be careful with updates.

Comment: note the undefined command error as copied from the log would say which command is undefined.  You have not shown the actual error message so it does not show which command is undefined.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer the workaround you mentioned worked for me :)

Comment: I had to switch to a new computer and as expected I run into the same problems now.. But for now the fix didnt solve the issue and I also saw that `xmpincl 2021/08/31 v2.3` should solve this issue but I didnt managed to solve it.